# How many Monero is mined in a day on average as of 2020 Jan?

Tags: mining, block-reward

Monero blocks are mined every 2 minutes. But how many are mined in a day on average? Is each mined block less the previously mined?

Comment: 1432 XMR per day as of now (2 XMR per block) x $70 USD = $100,240 mined a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of new Monero created each day gradually reduces until it hits 0.6 XMR per block (the tail emission). A great answer on this subject can be found [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1517/7493).

> Monero blocks are mined every 2 minutes. But how many are mined in a day on average?

One block mined every 2 minutes is 720 blocks per day.

As of this [moment](https://xmrchain.net/block/2012606), 1.99 XMR are produced for each block (so 1432 XMR per day).